# Python weird behavior - __name__mangling

Tags: python-3.x

I was reading about [Double Leading Underscore](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python#:%7E:text=A%20double%20underscore%20prefix%20causes,the%20class%20is%20extended%20later.) OR name mangling and stuck in my own experimenting code.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a) -> None:
        self.__args = a

    @property
    def args(self):
        """The args property."""
        print(dir(self))
        if "__args" in dir(self):
            print("yes __args is present")
        if "_A__args" in dir(self):
            print("yes _A__args is present")

        print(f"from inside self.__args - {self.__args}")
        result = self.__args
        return result





obj = A("check")
print(f"from outside self.__args - {obj.args}")
```

The output of above code is:

```
['_A__args', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'args']
yes _A__args is present
from inside self.__args - check
from outside self.__args - check
```

I'm wondering how it's able to access `self.__args` when there's no such attribute in `self`.

Comment: `dir` is an outside function. So it will see mangled version of the name. But `self` is inside the class. It can directly access the name.

Comment: @Asocia, makes sense, but when I used debugger inside `args` property and did `self.__args`, I got error - `*** AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__args'`

Comment: @user5319825 because there is no `__args`. When interpreter sees `__args` it knows to add `_classname_` in front of it before looking it in inside the class `__dict__`

Comment: @mx0, Why the interpreter doesn't adds `_classname_`  to `__args` when reading `result = self.__args` ?
OR even in `print(f"from inside self.__args - {self.__args}")`

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: no idea about this, hence asked!
I surmise on SO we got to answer to questions rather asking the same question for a given question!

Comment: No problem, I'm just trying to understand what part you don't understand :) Your @property example is more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name mangling happens every time you use a `__name` inside a class.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.__bar = bar
```

Attribute `__bar` doesn't exist inside the class, its name is automatically  changed to `_Foo__bar` when the class is created.

```
import dis
dis.dis(Foo)

Disassembly of __init__:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              4 STORE_ATTR               0 (_Foo__bar) # not __bar
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

When you try to access an attribute inside a class, its name is also automatically changed to `_Foo__bar`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.__bar = bar

    def hello(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.__bar}!")

import dis
dis.dis(Foo.hello)
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello ')
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (_Foo__bar) # not __bar
              8 FORMAT_VALUE             0
             10 BUILD_STRING             2
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

That's why this works:

```
foo = Foo("bar")
foo.hello()

>>> Hello bar!
```

However if you are outside of the class you have to use a full name (no name mangling outside of the class):

```
print(foo.__bar) # AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__bar'
print(foo._Foo__bar) # OK!

>>> 'bar'
```

This doesn't happen for attributes added later to the class:

```
foo = Foo("bar")
foo.__baz = 42
print(foo._Foo__baz) # AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '_Foo__baz'
print(foo.__baz) # OK!

>>> 'baz'
```

Because name mangling happens for every variable starting with double underscore, this is also possible:

```
_Foo__global = "I'm just a regular global variable"

class Foo:
    def hello(self):
        print(f"Hello, {__global}!")
        
Foo().hello()

>>> Hello, I'm just a regular global variable!
```

But please don't write code like this.